# Bootstrap date picker endDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have this bootstrap datepicker config:

```
datePickerConfig: {
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    endDate: new Date(),
    startDate: moment().subtract(1, 'year').toDate(),
    showOn: 'both',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: 'Select date',
    firstDay: moment.localeData().firstDayOfWeek(),
    dateFormat: 'L',
    autoclose: true
}

$('#someId').datepicker(datePickerConfig).datepicker('setDate', new Date())
```

Problem: In this case my input field will be empty:
[image]

If I do this:

```
$('someId').datepicker('setEndDate', '+1d');
```

I won't have empty input like above but in my datepicker will be possible select tomorrow date. See screen below:
[image]

What value should I set to `endDat`e, if want that I my datepicker last date, that had to be selected, is date of today. And when I init datepicker also I need date of today.

Comment: Resize your picture, so big picture with a lot of white make your question unreadable

Comment: Also, a comma is missing just after `endDate: new Date()`, maybe it's just a copy mistake ?

Comment: Yes. This is copy mistake.

Comment: Edited. Images are smaller.

Comment: I actually read the post 3 times but still can't understand what you say...

Comment: On screenshots you can see.. If i set today as end day input field is empty,but in datepicker tomorrow date is unselectable. Another case when I set as endDate tomorrow - input isn't empty, but in datepicker I have unnecessary tomorrow date. Question how to set endDate correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for attention.
Problem solved, I have added datesDisabled same as endDate!

```
endDate: '+1d',
datesDisabled: '+1d',
```

Comment: why dont you just do `endDate: '+0d'` ?

Comment: If I do this after rendering datepicker my input field will be empty.